# android - OutofMemoryError - bitmap size exceeds VM budget - on orientation change

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation, virtual-machine, out-of-memory

I have just started using Android. I have tried an apps with orientation change.

I am facing bitmap size exceeds VM budget. Have gone through many post in stackoverflow and could not figure out the problem. Exception is throwing at setContentView(R.layout.level1); in onCreate. This is happening when I change the orientation.

I have tried all forums and stackoverflow but could not figure it out. Trying to fix this for past 3 days.

Below class is being called from another activity on button click using intent and startActivity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("onCreate", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);
     if(!isOrientationChanged) //this part is executed if orientation is not changed (activity starts as usual) 
     { 
      drawableList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
      drawableList.add( getResources().getDrawable(colorEnum[0]));
      drawableList.add( getResources().getDrawable(colorEnum[1]));
     } 
     isOrientationChanged = false;   
   timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeView);
   colorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game_button);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreView);
    scoreView.setText("Score: " + score);
    hand.postDelayed(runThread, 0);
    super.onResume();
}


 @Override       
 public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()     {          
 isOrientationChanged = true;  
 return null; //as you are not returning an object you are not leaking memory here      
 } 

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    hand.removeCallbacks(runThread);
    super.onPause();
}

 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.RootView));
        System.gc();
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
       if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                Log.d("onDestroy","Inside loop to getting child "+((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
       hand.removeCallbacks( runThread); 
    }

/** The run thread. */
Thread runThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeView.setText("Time Left: " + timeLeftVal);
                :
                :
                :
        } else {
        changeColor();
        :
        :
            hand.postDelayed(runThread, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Change color.
 */
private void changeColor() {
    colorButton.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableList.get(randomNum));
```

}

1. In onCreate method, creating a drawable list and initializing it on first load.
2. Using Thread to set the button image background randomly
3. Calling unbindDrawables() method onDestroy so that on orientation change old view will be removed from memory.
4. hand.removeCallbacks(runThread) is also being called in onPause method
5. returned null in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

---

I have fixed the problem.
Small mistake resulted in this big issue. I have used Thread instead of Runnable in Handler. Hence, removeCallback didn't work as expected.

Comment: What is your manifest file setup to do ? , are you passing orientation changes to the activity to handle manually or you going for the old fashioned and often crashing destroy and rebuild ?

Comment: What is the size of the images you are loading ? How many images are you loading ?
As Chris said, in orientation change, all the activity is destoyed and reloaded. 
The problem is probably that the images of the previous orientation are still loaded whereas the images of next orientation are loading. The app crah because the WM is out of memory.
Calling  **unbindDrawables()** **System.gc()** don't ensure you that the images will be unloaded before loading next images.

Comment: Nice article about this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: I am not handling the orientation changes manually. As Jobesu stated, the problem might be unbindDrawables() and System.gc() might not have unloaded the previous images. UI has one button whose bg color changes randomly and two textview to show the data. Hence, there are there items which are being created and destroyed on every orientation change. I don't know how to remove the older views on orientation change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following links help:

[Eclipse Memory Analyser-Article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html)

[Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Google search for: *"Google IO 2011 Memory management for Android Apps"*